# Configure DEV-Domain for TYPO3 on macOS X by editing hosts file

Tags: macos, typo3, virtual-machine, hosts-file

I installed TYPO3 on a virtual machine (Ubuntu, Apache, MySQL) running in VirtualBox on macOS X.

It did work so far, I can access the TYPO3 installer using this URL:

```
http://1.2.3.123/t3projekt1
```

When accessing this URL the TYPO3 installer appears and tells me that everything is fine with this installation.

However, I can't manage to configure a development domain by editing the hosts file. I tried:

```
1.2.3.123/t3projekt1     typo3.dev.com
1.2.3.123                typo3.dev.com
```

Neither worked... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do not use slashes for any path in your hostfile. Just IP -> DOMAIN. Path to subdirectories and domain shoud be configured for apache separate in your httpconf

Comment: OK, I see. But why doesn't the 2. variant work (1.2.3.123     typo3.dev.com)?

Comment: Did you have a look at your Apache configuration httpd.conf for VirtualHost? You should define ServerName and DocumentRoot for typo3.dev.com. See also http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/vhosts/

Comment: what does "neither worked" mean? What errors do you get?